# Understand rust Option as_mut method

Tags: rust, option-type

Given a rust option:

```
let mut x = Some(3);
```

Why can I directly call `x.as_mut()`? As I can see from [the doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut), `as_mut` is defined as:

> `pub fn as_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T>` Converts from &mut
>   Option to Option<&mut T>.

which expects the first parameter to be `&mut self`, i.e. `&mut Option<T>`. Shouldn't I use `(&mut x).as_mut()` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here Rust's `.` operator does what you mean and implicitly borrows the variable. If it didn't, working with non-borrowed values would be annoying, because a value declared as e.g. `let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3]` couldn't be manipulated with e.g. `v.push(4)` without writing `(&mut v).push(4)`. The same would apply to fields, so if a struct *contained* a vector, you'd be unable to call `container.vec.push(element)` without explicitly borrowing `container.vec`, even if `container` itself was itself a mutable reference.

To prevent such noise C has two operators for field access, `.` and `->`, where the latter automatically dereferences. Rust's `.` intentionally goes ahead and does the borrowing or dereferencing needed for the method call to work.